# Cannot import .tsx file from .ts file (and vice versa)

Tags: typescript, webpack, babeljs

I have a project with `.ts` and `.tsx` files and I am trying to import a `.tsx` file from a `.ts` file, like so:

**src/index.ts**

```
import WriteEditor from './write_editor';
```

**src/write_editor.tsx**

```
import Events from './events';
import Actions from './actions';

export default class WriteEditor extends React.Component { /*...*/ }
```

Now TypeScript tells me

> ERROR in ./src/index.ts
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './write_editor' in '/Users/luke/Projekte/writejs/code/writejs/src'
>    @ ./src/index.ts 3:23-48
>    @ multi ./src/index.ts

So I tried this:

**src/index.ts**

```
import WriteEditor from './write_editor.tsx';
```

Now my IDE tells me not to write the extensions `tsx` and I get an errors in **src/write_editor.tsx** because TypeScript cannot find my `.ts` files from a `.tsx` file.

Then I went to rename the imports and added the `.ts` extensions

```
import Events from './events.ts';
import Actions from './actions.ts';
```

Now I am getting tons or errors telling me not to write extensions at all.

So how can we import `tsx` from `ts` and vice versa?

Comment: Your question mentions `write_editor.jsx` and `write_editor.tsx`. Why do you have a `.jsx` file?

Comment: Oh sorry that is a typo, it's all `tsx`

Comment: Have you configured Webpack to auto-append the `.ts` and `.tsx` extensions?

Comment: I did, this is my webpack config https://gist.github.com/LukasBombach/38b5b1f19da819e6f4effee743162c6d

Comment: Oh wait, what do you mean with auto-append?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

When you write

```
import WriteEditor from './write_editor';
```

Webpack will automatically look for

- `./write_editor`
- `./write_editor.js`
- `./write_editor.json`
- (And a few others)

Since you're using `.ts` and `.tsx`, you need to tell it to look for those too in your Webpack config using [`resolve.extensions`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-extensions):

```
{
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".json", ".ts", ".tsx"],
  },
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In my case, I got same error when using **typescript-eslint**. It is an app created by **create-react-app**.

The way is by adding this code in **.eslintrc.js**.

```
module.exports = {
  // ...
  settings: {
    'import/resolver': {
      'node': {
        'extensions': ['.js','.jsx','.ts','.tsx']
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had renamed a `.jsx` file to `.tsx` and had to delete Parcel's cache to get it to resolve.